# WPF display content based on treeview selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I was able to retrieve selected item value from my treeview. Now I want to change the content in ScrollViewer control based on that value. I'm trying to display property values of Facility object which contains Containments which contains Tanks.

I'm new to programming sorry if my explanation is not clear enough.
Thank you.

**MyWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:VisioFacilityExportViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FacilityTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Facility ID:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].FacilityID}"/>
            <Label Content="Address:" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].Address}"/>
            <Label Content="Description:" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].Description}"/>
            <Label Content="Layout And Drainage:" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].LayoutAndDrainage}"/>
            <Label Content="Latitude:" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].Latitude}"/>
            <Label Content="Longitude:" Grid.Row="5"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].Longitude}"/>
            <Label Content="City:" Grid.Row="6"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].City.Name}"/>
            <Label Content="County:" Grid.Row="7"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].County.Name}"/>
            <Label Content="Name:" Grid.Row="8"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].Name}"/>
            <Label Content="Run:" Grid.Row="9"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].Run}"/>
            <Label Content="Surface Flow Direction:" Grid.Row="10"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].SurfaceFlowDirection}"/>
            <Label Content="API Number:" Grid.Row="11"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].APINumber}"/>
            <Label Content="Distance To Navigable Waters:" Grid.Row="12"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].DistanceToNavigableWaters}"/>
            <Label Content="Project Phase:" Grid.Row="13"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].APINumber}"/>
            <Label Content="Unique ID:" Grid.Row="14"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].UniqueID}"/>
            <Label Content="Operational Field:" Grid.Row="15"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].OperationalField}"/>
            <Label Content="Facility Type:" Grid.Row="16"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].FacilityType}"/>
            <Label Content="Project Number:" Grid.Row="17"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="17" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].ProjectNumber}"/>
            <Label Content="Project Phase:" Grid.Row="18"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].ProjectPhase}"/>
            <Label Content="Report Number:" Grid.Row="19"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListFacilities[0].ReportNumber}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContainmentTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Name:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].Name}"/>
            <Label Content="Height:" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].Height}"/>
            <Label Content="Diameter:" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].TankPadHeight}"/>
            <Label Content="County:" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].TankPadWidth}"/>
            <Label Content="Inner Length:" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].TankPadLength}"/>
            <Label Content="Inner Width:" Grid.Row="5"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].InnerLength}"/>
            <Label Content="Top Length:" Grid.Row="6"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].InnerWidth}"/>
            <Label Content="Top Width:" Grid.Row="7"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].TopLength}"/>
            <Label Content="Construction:" Grid.Row="8"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].TopWidth}"/>
            <Label Content="Fill Materials:" Grid.Row="9"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"  Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].Construction}"/>
            <Label Content="Fill Material Height (Top):" Grid.Row="10"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"  Text="{Binding ListContainments[0].Diameter}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TanksTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Name:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].Name}"/>
            <Label Content="Height:" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].Height}"/>
            <Label Content="Diameter:" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].Diameter}"/>
            <Label Content="Is in Service:" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].IsInService}"/>
            <Label Content="Is on Pad:" Grid.Row="4"/>
            <CheckBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" IsChecked="{Binding ListTanks[0].IsOnPad}"/>
            <Label Content="Contents:" Grid.Row="5"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].Contents}"/>
            <Label Content="Year Constructed:" Grid.Row="6"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].YearConstructed}"/>
            <Label Content="Material:" Grid.Row="7"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].Material}"/>
            <Label Content="Is Portable:" Grid.Row="8"/>
            <CheckBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" IsChecked="{Binding ListTanks[0].IsPortable}"/>
            <Label Content="Is Isolated:" Grid.Row="9"/>
            <CheckBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" IsChecked="{Binding ListTanks[0].IsIsolated}"/>
            <Label Content="Quantity:" Grid.Row="10"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Text="{Binding ListTanks[0].Quantity}"/>
            <Label Content="Orientation:" Grid.Row="11"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="5" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView Name="trvFacility" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" Padding="10" Margin="5" Width="220">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type entities:MenuItemCust}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
               DataTemplate here
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" Height="25" Margin="0,0,5,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

**MyWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class VisioFacilityExportViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VisioFacilityExportViewModel()
    {
        _lstFacilities = new ObservableCollection<Facility>(DatabaseHandler.GetFacilities().Where(f => f.FacilityID == 2015012314001933));
        _lstContainments = _lstFacilities[0].Containment;
        _lstTanks = _lstContainments[0].Tanks;
        List<MenuItemCust> lstRoot = new List<MenuItemCust>();
        List<MenuItemCust> lstContainment = new List<MenuItemCust>();
        List<MenuItemCust> lstTanks = new List<MenuItemCust>();
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItemCust>();
        foreach (var f in _lstFacilities)
        {
            foreach (var c in f.Containment)
            {
                lstTanks.AddRange(c.Tanks.Select(t => new MenuItemCust { Name = t.Name, Info = "Tanks"}));
                lstContainment.Add(new MenuItemCust { Name = c.Name, Children = lstTanks, Info = "Containment" });
            }
            lstRoot.Add(new MenuItemCust { Name = "Containment", Children = lstContainment, Info = "Facility"});
            MenuItems.Add(new MenuItemCust { Name = "Facility", Children = lstRoot });
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Tank> _lstTanks;
    public ObservableCollection<Tank> ListTanks
    {
        get { return _lstTanks; }
        set
        {
            _lstTanks = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ListTanks");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Containment> _lstContainments;
    public ObservableCollection<Containment> ListContainments
    {
        get { return _lstContainments; }
        set
        {
            _lstContainments = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ListContainments");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Facility> _lstFacilities;
    public ObservableCollection<Facility> ListFacilities
    {
        get { return _lstFacilities; }
        set
        {
            _lstFacilities = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ListFacilities");
        }
    }
    private List<MenuItemCust> _menuItems;
    public List<MenuItemCust> MenuItems
    {
        get { return _menuItems; }
        set
        {
            _menuItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MenuItems");
        }
    }

    private static object _selectedItem = null;
    public static object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        private set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnSelectedItemChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void OnSelectedItemChanged()
    {
        var item = (MenuItemCust) SelectedItem;
        if (item.Name == "Facility")
        {

        }
        else if (item.Info == "Containment")
        {

        }
        else if (item.Info == "Tanks")
        {

        }
    }
    #region iNotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is display informations in a UserControl which will contains a grid with differents controls like textblock and textbox.
So you are going to create a new UserControl named FacilityView and FacilityViewModel and the FacilityView will contains a grid with ur Facility Ojbect property
First of all, I would create an property in MyWindowViewModel called

```
private Facility currentFacility;

public Facility CurrentFacility
{
 get{return currentFacility;}
 set{ currentFacility = value ;
 notifyPropertyChange("CurrentFacility")    
}
```

In your MainWindowsView (xaml)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localAdder:FacilityViewModel}">
        <localAdder:FacilityView />
</DataTemplate>

<UserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
 Content="{Binding CurrentFacility,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
</UserControl>
```

And in  your SelectedItem you would

```
if (selectedItem is Facility)
{
CurrentFacility = new FacilityViewModel(selectedItem as Facility);     
}
```

Sry for the bad indentation im not use to this writing code.

EDIT2:

Okay, you have 2 choice, first of all u can create a BaseViewModel which will implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

FacilityViewModel : BaseViewModel

TankViewModel : BaseViewModel

ContainmentViewModel : BaseViewModel

This way you will change CurrentFacilityViewModel to CurrentBaseViewModel

```
private BaseViewModel currentBaseXXX;

public BaseViewModel CurrentBaseXXX
{
 get{return currentBaseXXX;}
 set{ currentBaseXXX= value ;
 notifyPropertyChange("CurrentBaseXXX")    
}
```

And in  your SelectedItem you would

```
if (selectedItem is Facility)
{
CurrentBaseXXX= new FacilityViewModel(selectedItem as Facility);     
}
if (selectedItem is Tank)
{
CurrentBaseXXX= new TankViewModel(selectedItem as Tank);     
}
if (selectedItem is Containers)
{
CurrentBaseXXX= new ContainersViewModel(selectedItem as Containers);     
}
```

Options2

You would have 3 current so

CurrentFacilityVM

CurrentTankVM

CurrentContainerVM

And in  your SelectedItem you would

```
CurrentFacilityVM = null;

CurrentTankVM =null;

CurrentContainerVM =null;
if (selectedItem is Facility)
{
CurrentFacilityVM = new FacilityViewModel(selectedItem as Facility);     
}
if (selectedItem is Tank)
{
CurrentTankVM = new TankViewModel(selectedItem as Tank);     
}
if (selectedItem is Containers)
{
CurrentContainerVM = new ContainersViewModel(selectedItem as Containers);     
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Guillaume. Following your logic I supposed to have two more UserControls one for Containment and one for Tank. Assume I made them the same way but how I can toggle between them based on treeview selecteditem?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically Load the data template based on Type. Refer the below. You can toggle the template by change the instance of the SelectedItem to a Different class.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Facility}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FacilityName}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Containment}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContainmentName}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Tank}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TankName}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="5" Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding }"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" Height="25" Margin="0,0,5,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>

public partial class Download : Window
{
    public Download()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new VisioFacilityExportViewModel();
    }
}

public class VisioFacilityExportViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VisioFacilityExportViewModel()
    {
        //SelectedItem = new Facility() { FacilityName = "Facility" };
        //SelectedItem = new Tank() { TankName = "Tank" };
        SelectedItem = new Containment() { ContainmentName = "Containment" };
    }

    private  object _selectedItem = null;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        private set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }


    #region iNotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    #endregion
}

public class Tank
{
    private string myVar;

    public string TankName
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }

}
class Facility
{

    private string myVar;

    public string FacilityName
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
}
class Containment
{
    private string myVar;

    public string ContainmentName
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
}
```